# import/export class method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing on class components, I have very large methods and I wanted to transfer them to a file, but I don’t know how to do it. Loss of context occurs

```
import { handleChange } from './methods';    

class Test extends Component {
  state = {number: 42}

  render() {
    const { number } = this.state;
    return(
      <MyComponent number={number} onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
    );
  }

}

export default Test;

// method.js
export const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log("this is:", this)
    const { data } = this.state;
    const { name, value, key} = e.target;

    this.setState({
        data: {
            ...data,
            [key]: data[key].set(name, value)
        }
    });
}
```

In the console *this is: undefined*  Method should be outside the class.  How fix?

Comment: Relevant: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429) | [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379)

Comment: Pass the instance as an argument or using `.call()`.

Comment: "*I have very large methods*" - instead of moving the large method to a separate file, break it down into smaller parts. Then move all the parts that *don't* have anything to do with the whole component directly to separate functions in a separate module.

Comment: @Bergi thanks, run! `const handleChange = (e, self) => {` and `onChange={e => handleChange(e, this)`